# How do I make sure that the execution of the webpage is only proceeded if the api result is returned?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

In

ngOninit() of the app.component, we have called an `api` that basically returns the `true/false`. Based on that, 'type' a class is injected into the document.body i.e. IsVisible. And in the Sass of app.component it disables the logos and other contents in the web page.

api call

```
const res= app.services.getIsActiveType().toPromise();
document.body.ClassList.Add(res.type);
```

in sass

```
body {
  &.Type{
    logos {
      dispaly: none;     
    }
   }
  }
```

But when deployed to the real server we have an issue with the speed which results in calling and returning the response being delayed by around 6,7 seconds hence the content is visible until the webapi returns a result.

Now, shall we improve the speed of the server or change the logic because the particular role should not see those contents but the slow speed results in showing it for a while.

What should I do? Even if a speed is improved I cannot rely on that.

I searched and solutuon is to use resolvers but I don't know much about that since new to angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:** you can invert the behavior of the CSS class so that it shows instead of hides stuff and keep things hidden by default

**Approach 2:** you can use [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) to wait for API's response, the special thing about APP_INITIALIZER is that it will be called even before root component's initialization and angular will wait until it gets resolved, here's the sample code:

```
const initializer = (apiService: ApiService) => {
    return () => {
        return apiService.getIsActiveType()
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                document.body.classList.add(res.type);
            });
    };
}
```

register this initializer in app module like this:

```
@NgModule({
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initializer,
        deps: [ApiService],
        multi: true,
    },
],
```

})
export class AppModule { }

if you go with this approach, also optimize API response so that user is not staring at a blank white screen for like 6-7 seconds

Comment: hi, thanks, mind if I ask where to put the initializer code I mean the first block const initializer = (apiService: ApiService) = ......?

Comment: well you can put it in same file as app module, just above it or create a separate file and import it from there, it's upto you.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try something like:

```
app.services
.getIsActiveType()
.subscribe( (result:any) => {
    document.body.ClassList.Add(result.type);
} );
```

Comment: hi, but this also returns an observables asynchronously hence the same result.

Comment: ? is it ? can you please help me on this?

Comment: Sorry, if it doesn't work for you, As you said, maybe try with a resolver service in order to get data before charge the page: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

1. If content is authorized for a specific user role, that content should not be visible until the role is confirmed.
2. Utilize Angular's template resources like `*ngIf` if you want to keep content hidden from the view. Hiding it with CSS is not secure.
3. I would recommend using observables instead of `.toPromise()` as this feature will eventually become deprecated in RxJS 7.x (Angular still uses 6.x for now.)